# Convert varchar(max) to geography

Tags: sql, sql-server, polygon, sqlgeography

I have an SQL table containing multipolygons (country borders) in varchar(max) format.

[image: Screenshot of the data]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQBHc.png)

I want to convert them into geography format so that I can intersect them with geographical points (also in geography format).

So far I've tried it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Geoboundaries
ADD [GeoLocation] GEOGRAPHY

INSERT INTO [GeoLocation]  
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(shapeGeometry,4326)
FROM dbo.Geoboundaries
```

Unfortunately, I am always getting following error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Post the content and the error as text in the question itself. The image shows that the text is invalid. You can't parse this any  more than you can parse `Potato` as a date or number. You'll have to fix the bad text.

Comment: Use UPDATE instead of INSERT to add data to your table's new column.

Comment: The geometry text is not a WKT. Remove the SRID=4326; -part from it and perhaps it will work, but hard to say since you attach an image of incomplete text.

Comment: Well-Known-Text doesn't allow an `SRID` prefix. You'll have to split the text, parse the WKT and specify the SRID separately. Your own code already passes the SRID separately. If you're OK with hard-coding the SRID, you could *remove* it from the text with `REPLACE(shapeGeometry,'SRID=4326')`

Answer (score 2):

That's not valid WKT. The [Well-Known-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry) format doesn't have an SRID prefix. You'll have to either split the string and extract the parts, or remove the SRID prefix entirely with `REPLACE(shapeGeometry,'SRID=4326;','')`.

```
INSERT INTO [GeoLocation]  
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(
                      REPLACE(shapeGeometry,'SRID=4326;',''),
                      4326)
FROM dbo.Geoboundaries
```

If multiple SRIDs are possible, you could extract it as a substring and parse it with `cast(SUBSTRING(shapeGeometry,6,4) as int)`

If you want to fill `Geolocation` in the same row though, you need to use UPDATE, not INSERT.

```
UPDATE Geoboundaries
SET [GeoLocation] = GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(
                        REPLACE(shapeGeometry, 'SRID=4326;', ''),
                        4326)
```

Comment: I'd guess OP wants `UPDATE dbo.Geoboundaries SET [GeoLocation] = ...`.

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't noticed that `GeoLocation` is a column in the same table

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good, but there is one small error. You need to use the @ symbol before the shapeGeometry parameter in the STGeomFromText function. This is because the @ symbol tells SQL Server that the parameter is a variable. So, your code should look like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Geoboundaries
ADD [GeoLocation] GEOGRAPHY

INSERT INTO [GeoLocation]
SELECT GEOGRAPHY::STGeomFromText(@shapeGeometry, 4326)
FROM dbo.Geoboundaries
```

Once you have made this change, your code should work as expected.